# can StructureMap auto-register Handler<T> for IHandler<T>?

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, ioc-container, structuremap, auto-registration

I posted [an issue](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/issues/328) on SM repo.

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817187/how-do-i-use-structuremap-with-generic-unclosed-types-using-scan-with-a-greedy), but I'd like to localize a problem.

Let's say I have generic interface `IPrinter<T>` and its generic implementation `Printer<T>`. I'd like StructureMap to resolve the concrete closed type `Printer<string>` when I do `container.GetInstance<IPrinter<string>>`.

Explicit registration works OK here:

`container.Configure(r => r.For(typeof (IPrinter<>)).Use(typeof (Printer<>)));`

But the scan stuff fails: `RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface()` results in `202 No Default Instance defined` StructureMap exception when I'm trying to resolve `IPrinter<string>`.

Is there a way to accomplish the behavior I want without explicit configuration?

Answer (score 1):

*ConnectImplementationsToTypeClosing()* works just fine but you have to know how it works. It registers types with *Add()* method which is quite different in its behavior than registrations done with *Use()* method. Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365025/4336786). In short when you get 202 error code that does not mean you have not registered any concrete types for requested plugin type. It could be the case that you have registered them more than one and no default instance is specified.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

By this: "It could be the case that you have registered them more than one and no default instance is specified" I meant that more than one implementations of the same plugin type was registered, e.g. for

```
IPrinter<string>
```

you have defined:

```
StringPrinter1 : IPrinter<string> and StringPrinter2 : IPrinter<string>
```

Not that you are allowed to register only one type for IPrinter<>.

When you want to register multiple implementations of the same generic plugin type, e.g.

```
IPrinter<string>
```

then I advise to use:

```
var container = new Container(c => c.Scan(s => s.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IHandler<>)).NameBy(t => t.Name)));
```

to have named registrations and then resolve them by name explicitly:

```
var stringPrinter1 = container.GetInstance<IPrinter<string>>("StringPrinter1");
```

or by using such registration:

```
c.For<IMyTypeUsingPrinter>().Use<MyTypeUsingPrinter>().Ctor<IPrinter<string>>().Named("StringPrinter1");
```

them *MyTypeUsingPrinter* would have injected StringPrinter1 as IPrinter< string > dependency.

Comment: Thanks! Check the update, I made it more clear. `.For(typeof (IPrinter<>)).Use(typeof (Printer<>)` works as well, but what I'm looking for is truly automatic way to register simple cases. And I think it's a simple one if there is only one (generic) implementation of a generic interface.

Comment: I'm aware of explicit ways to do it. What I'm looking for is the *automatic* one, by which I mean I want to write just the line `RegisterConcreteTypesAgainstTheFirstInterface()`. I don't want to list all the generic types I have in my app to have them registered.

Comment: Ok, got it now :) I wouldn't advise to use such approach but if you really need it you can write custom convention that would register types accordingly.

Comment: I didn't have to write a convention in order to get it work automagically with non-generic types, so I want to know what is special about generic ones.